# On linear tranformations and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a linear transformation on a n dimensional vector space $V$ and if $A^{n-1}v \not= 0$ but $A^nv = 0$ for some $v\in V$. Find the eigenvalues of $A$.

I can show that 0 is an eigenvalue of A by letting $x=A^{n-1}v \not= 0$ be a eigenvector, but then i cant find anymore. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove that the vectors $v,Av,A^2v,\ldots,A^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent, and therefore form a basis of $V$. You could prove this from the fact that each $A^{n-k}v$ is linearly independent of its images $A^{n-k+1}v,\ldots,A^{n-1}v$ (this basically shows that each inclusion $0\subset\ker A\subset\ker A^2\subset\cdots\subset\ker A^n$ is strict), or by showing that each non-trivial relation would lead to a contradiction by applying a power of $A$ to it that kills all terms but one.

Once this is done, you get that $A$ is nilpotent: $A^n=0$, and this is clearly incompatible with having any other eigenvalue than$~0$.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is any other eigenvalue than the zero you found.

claim: $0$ is the only eigenvalue of the matrix $A.$

proof: i will work the proof for the case $n = 3.$ you can see the main idea in this simple case. you are given some $v \neq 0$ that satisfies $A^2v \neq 0$ but $A^3v= 0.$  first we show that $\{v, Av, A^2v \}$ is a linearly independent set. suppose $$ av + b Av + cA^2v = 0$$ for some scalars $a, b, c.$ multiply the on the left by $A^2$ and use the fact $A^2v \neq 0$ to conclude $a = 0.$ now multiply by $A$ to see $b = 0,$ finally $c = 0.$ so $v, Av, A^2v$ is linearly independent.

suppose $av + bAv + cA^2v$ is a nonzero eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to a nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda,$  then $$A(av + bAv + cA^2v) = \lambda(av+bAv + cA^2v)$$

trying the same trick of multiplying the equation by $A^2$ on the left and using $\lambda \neq 0,$ we get $a = 0$. same as before, show $b = 0$ and $c = 0.$

but this contradicts that the eigenvector is nonzero. therefor, the assumption $\lambda \neq 0$ cannot hold. this proves the claim.

p.s. all this can be avoided if you use big guns like cayley-hamilton theorem, minimal polynomial etc.